# Permissions and groups in fstab ignored

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I need to read and write to an usb ntfs pendrive through `www-data` group (that has uid 33) so I have added

```
UUID=34A0456D004536A0 /home/mypath ntfs-3g rw,defaults,uid=1000,gid=33,dmode=770,fmode=660,dmask=007,fmask=117,auto 0 0
```

the disk is mounted but with generic permissions applied to all USB drivers ignoring everything I placed in fstab but mount path that is correct.

I have also used  sudo ntfsusermap to generate a mapping file to place in .NTFS-3G folder in the drive.

What could be the reason?
How can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see all the mount options in my `mount.ntfs(8)` manual. Can you add to your question a link to an online resource that describes *all* the options you are using? Thanks

Comment: @xhienne You can check them using `man mount` command in terminal

Comment: Some are not there either

Comment: I think `fstab` only works for USB drives in the way you intend if they are plugged at boot time. Is that your case? Maybe [udev rules](https://wiki.debian.org/udev) is an alternative solution.

Comment: Please show the output of the commands `mount /home/mypath` and `mount | grep /home/mypath`.  Though it does sound like something other than `fstab` is mounting your device.

Comment: AFAIK, `dmode` and `fmode` are vboxsf options (virtualbox shared folders), not ntfs-3g ones. Maybe there's some confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit *udisk2* mount options with:

`sudo nano /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf`

and add

```
[defaults]
ntfs_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,windows_names
ntfs_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,umask,dmask,fmask,locale,norecover,ignore_case,windows_names,compression,nocompression,big_writes
```

if still doesn't work:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb-disks.rules
```

and add this

```
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ntfs", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}="ntfs-3g"
```

Comment: After adding mount_options.conf now works

Answer (score 1):

According to `man mount.ntfs-3g`, there are no `fmode` or `dmode` options. And under `man mount` the `dmode` option exists, but it is for udf ("Universal Disk Format" filesystem) only.

Also - do not use a comma to end the `fs_mntops` field in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: in another installation I used them and they work correctly on NTFS with ntfs-3g

Comment: @Andrea: I don't know what to tell you w/o more info; this is what the system manuals say.

Comment: @AndreaF What version of ntfs-3g are you using? [Searching the ntfs-3g repository](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atuxera%2Fntfs-3g+fmode&type=code) for the term `fmode` yields no results at all, in contrast to [searching for `fmask`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atuxera%2Fntfs-3g+fmask&type=code). You can also check [the file _ntfs-3g/src/ntfs-3g_common.c_](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/blob/75dcdc2cf37478fad6c0e3427403d198b554951d/src/ntfs-3g_common.c#L96), which lists all the options.